# Javascript .match plus jQuery keyup(), double match and strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Not really good in regular expression, but why when a match is found `console.log` fires two times?

```
$('#name').keyup(function() {
    var regex = /[\€]/g;
    var count = (m = $(this).val().match(regex)) ? m.length : 0; // Num matches
    console.log(count);
});
```

Output with 'hello':

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

After adding '€' symbol to 'hello' we have:

```
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
```

After adding 'h' symbol to 'hello€' we have:

```
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
```

Shouldn't be just one `1` after adding '€' to 'hello'?

Comment: you may want to handle the keypress event instead of the keyup event, this should remove the event fires for ctrl, alt, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keyup intercepts control keys as well. I guess there's no dedicated key for euro on your keyboard, so you hit something like `alt-E` to enter it. Alt key causes the handler to fire twice.

Comment: Right!There is no dedicated euro symbol key (it's combo Alt Gr + 'E'). Do you think that the double call of `.keyup()` could be a problem when using `count`?

Comment: @Gremo your count variable is local to the keyup handler, so they wont interfere with each other - you will just get the same answers printed multiple times.